# Electron Builder- DMG in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, electron-builder, dmg

Electron builder DMG packaging cannot be performed in non Mac platforms according to comments of [isuues](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/811).

But we can use package dmgs using [mkfs.hfsplus](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mkfs.hfsplus.8.html). How to integrate electron packager with hfsplus for a direct build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either a Makefile or the package.json straight away and chain those commands together.

```
genisoimage -q -V <A-name-of-your-choice> -D -R -apple -no-pad -m "LICENSE" -m "LICENSES.chromium.html" -m "version" -o ./dist/<A-name-of-your-choice>.dmg ./path/to/dist
```

Comment: It would be very useful to provide an example :)

Comment: Right. Example added.